# Included Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times + initMap is not a function (Invalid Value)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have embedded Google Map API (Javascript) in my page. However, the map only loads after I refresh the page once.

When I check the console, there are two errors with Google Maps.

```
❌You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. 
js?key=<my_key>&callback=initMap:140 
This may cause unexpected errors.

❌Uncaught (in promise) 
xd {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new xd (https://maps.googleapis.com/<my_key>&callback=initMap:138:113"}
message: "initMap is not a function"
name: "InvalidValueError"
stack: "Error↵    at new xd
```

1) I think I didn't call the API multiple times, but somehow there is an error message on this.

2) As for the second one, I do realize that I use a script src (from the documentation) that includes initMap function, though I haven't define it yet.
I did saw the example from the documentation but I'm not sure how I should I use it in this case.

Show.html.erb

```html
<div id="map"
  style="width: 100%;
  height: 300px;"
  data-markers="<%= @markers.to_json %>"
></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= ENV['GOOGLE_API_BROWSER_KEY'] %>&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

javascript/packs/map.js

```html
import GMaps from 'gmaps/gmaps.js';

const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
if (mapElement) {
  const map = new GMaps({ el: '#map', lat: 0, lng: 0 });
  const markers = JSON.parse(mapElement.dataset.markers);
  map.addMarkers(markers);
  if (markers.length === 0) {
    map.setZoom(2);
  } else if (markers.length === 1) {
    map.setCenter(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng);
    map.setZoom(14);
  } else {
    map.fitLatLngBounds(markers);
  }
}
```

Application.html.erb

```html
     <%= yield %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_API_BROWSER_KEY']}" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
      <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
      <%= javascript_pack_tag "map" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include the Google Maps API twice, once in Show.html.erb which will be loaded inside the Application.html.erb I believe and there again you yield the JavaScript Google Maps API a second time. The error states that it is on line 140 that it is included a second time and that is the one with the initMap so inside Show.html.erb which is probably included inside an index and/or Application.html.erb so I suggest looking at the page source to get a complete HTML view of the final loaded page and there on line 140 you probably will see the second inclusion

Secondly if a function isn't declared yet you MUST not call it so now you call I initMap but that function doesn't exist. So start with removing the script include inside Show.html.erb or remove the yield in Application.html.erb and also remove the initMap call until the map works as supposed then go on to initMap declaration.

JS will stop loading or working if there is a severe error so having both included the API twice and calling a non existing function will get you I to trouble.

Do make sure that the API is loaded before the map is used or the API is called and since JS is non blocking sync wait until ready state of the document before doing anything.

Edit: are you also sure that on refresh that it is not maintaining the Google Maps API include? So you refresh full page or just a section of it?

Comment: I removed script scr with initMap from Show.html.erb and it works now. Thank you!!!
>>reply to Edit: I mean that the map will not display anything unless I refresh the page, and it's always work well after a refresh

Comment: Would be nice if you upvote my answer and I would be glad to take another look. Seems that there is an issue with loading order then and after refresh, not hard refresh, part of the page might be cached and therefore will only include the missing on. So I think that the map is not loaded when it needs to be or you try loading the map when the API is not yet loaded. I would need to see the page source and some console outputs

Comment: I thought I did upvote your answer already?, let me vote it again.
I think that the map didn't load initially because I included the API twice before, which causes an issue in loading the map. and that refreshing the page kinda triggers the api once again. As mentioned the previous comment, everything works accordingly after I remove api src from Show.html.erb, so there's no error message in the console anymore